# Spring JPA entity doesn't update when i use getReferenceId() in transactional function

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, entitymanager

The contents of the database do not change despite the normal communication and modification of the contents to be modified through the DTO.

entity code like this

```java
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Table(indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "title"),
        @Index(columnList = "createdAt"),
        @Index(columnList = "createdBy")
})
@Entity
public class Article extends AuditingFields{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter @Column(nullable = false) private String title; 
    @Setter @Column(nullable = false, length = 10000) private String content;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinTable(
            name = "article_hashtag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "articleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hashtagId")
    )
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Hashtag> hashtags = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OrderBy("createdAt DESC") 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude 
    private final Set<ArticleComment> articleComments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Setter @ManyToOne(optional = false) @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private UserAccount userAccount; //유저 계정 id

    protected Article() {} 
    public Article(UserAccount userAccount,String title, String content) {
        this.userAccount = userAccount;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public static Article of(UserAccount userAccount, String title, String content) {
        return new Article(userAccount, title, content);
    }

    public void addHashtag(Hashtag hashtag){
        this.getHashtags().add(hashtag);
    }

    public void addHashtags(Collection<Hashtag> hashtags){
        this.getHashtags().addAll(hashtags);
    }

    public void clearHashtags(){
        this.getHashtags().clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Article article)) return false;
        return this.getId() != null &&  this.getId().equals(article.id);
        
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getId());
    }
}
```

problem method like this

```java
public void updateArticle(Long articleId, ArticleDto dto) {
        try {
            Article article = articleRepository.getReferenceById(articleId);
            UserAccount userAccount = userAccountRepository.getReferenceById(dto.userAccountDto().userId());
            if (article.getUserAccount().equals(userAccount)) {
                if (dto.title() != null) {
                    article.setTitle(dto.title());
                }
                if (dto.content() != null) {
                    article.setContent(dto.content());
                }

                Set<Long> hashtagIds = article.getHashtags().stream()
                        .map(Hashtag::getId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
                article.clearHashtags();
                articleRepository.save(article);
                articleRepository.flush();

                hashtagIds.forEach(hashtagService::deleteHashtagWithoutArticles);

                Set<Hashtag> hashtags = renewHashtagsFromContent(dto.content());
                article.addHashtags(hashtags);
            }
           
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            log.warn("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Strangely, when you call the "Article" class through the "findById" function, it updates normally

when i call updateMethod, entity modified right away

I guess the cause was related to "lazy loading". Or maybe "Entity Manager" can't do "dirty check"?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know the cause of the above mentioned problem and how to solve it.

Please understand that I may not be able to express my English properly because I am not good at it.